# patchValue now working initializing FormArray values

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I have a table of cashflows. Each cashFlow has a variable number of periods. 
when I click on a cashflow, I am trying to populate a component so the period values can be edited.  The cashflow name and start/end dates are populating.
I have an array of periods, i have text boxes showing for each period.

**I can not get the initial values to show in the textboxes.

I am trying to get either patchValue or setValue to work.**

I have carefully reviewed the 12 questions suggested as related by SO. One gave me an idea to try but it ultimately did not solve my problem.

Here is cashFlowDetailComponent.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit , Input, Output, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
import {cashFlow, cashFlowPeriod} from '../cashflow'
import { IMyDpOptions, IMyDateModel, IMyDate } from 'mydatepicker';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-cashflow-detail',
  templateUrl: './cashflow-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cashflow-detail.component.css']
})
export class CashflowDetailComponent implements OnInit {



  myFormGroup: FormGroup;
  myCashFlow: cashFlow;


  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { 

   }

    //called by parent component when cashFlow is clicked.
  buildForm(cf_: cashFlow): void {
    //return;
    this.myFormGroup = null;
    this.myCashFlow = cf_;
    if (cf_ == null) { return;}
    const a :FormArray = this.fb.array([]); 



    this.myCashFlow.periods.forEach(cfp => {

      a.push(this.cfpGroup(cfp));
    })

     //set up the form w/ header controls, add in the periods array
    this.myFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      cashFlowName: this.myCashFlow.cashFlowName,
      startDate: this.threePartDateFromDate( this.myCashFlow.startDate),
      endDate: this.threePartDateFromDate( this.myCashFlow.endDate),
      periods:a
    });



       this.myFormGroup.controls['periods'].controls[i].controls['value1'].setValue(this.myCashFlow.periods[i].value1);
    //}



  }//end of buildform

  //return a simple FormGroup , this will cause 'periods' to be an FormArray of FormGroups,  each w/ 1 control
  cfpGroup(cfp_ : cashFlowPeriod) :FormGroup{
    const g : FormGroup = this.fb.group({
      value1: cfp_.value1
    });
    //  g.patchValue(cfp_);   //suggested in one of the related SO questions. No Joy.
    return g;
  }


  //needed to patch the myDatePicker. It works, it may not be pretty or efficient... 
  threePartDateFromDate(d_: string): any {
    const date_ = new Date(d_);

    return {
      date: {
        year: date_.getFullYear(),
        month: date_.getMonth()+1,
        day: date_.getDate()}
    }

  }
}
```

and here is my template

```
    <div *ngIf="myCashFlow && myFormGroup" [formGroup]="myFormGroup">

      <table style="margin:7px 7px 7px 7px">
            <tr>
          <td class="fieldLabel">Cash Flow Name</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text"
                   formControlName="cashFlowName"
                   style="width:175px;" />
          </td>
        </tr>


      </table>




   <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td *ngFor="let cfp of myCashFlow.periods,let i=index">{{cfp.periodName}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td *ngFor="let cfp of myCashFlow.periods, let i=index" style="padding:7px;">
        <input type="text"
               [id]="cfp.periodName"
               style="width:35px;" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you think anyone would want to go through this much of code?? You should create a simplified reproducible example on stackblitz/plunkr

Answer (score 0):

thank  you saksham for suggesting i put this in  stackblitz
learn a new skill everyday it seems

please find that here.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qcjxri

I was able to identify the problem by comparing the stackblitz code carefully w/ this example by vic rubba
https://dev.to/crazedvic/using-patchvalue-on-formarrays-in-angular-7-2c8c

1. My  which encapsulates the ngFOR needed a  `formArrayName="periods"`   no brackets
2. my  needed a `[formGroupName]="periodIndex"`  which is the index for the for.  If someone can explain that, id appreciate it. That was the magic final piece.
3. the  needed `formControlName="value1"`   no brackets

I have read MANY articles on FormGroup and FormArray and patchValue over the past two days. Somehow pts 2 and 3 have escaped my attention. I am interested to go back and read those articles again.

I hope this helps someone.

The HTML template in its entirety is on stackBlitz, buts i post it here so you can see where my 3 points come in context.

```
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td *ngFor="let cfp of myCashFlow.periods,let i=index">{{cfp.periodName}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr  formArrayName="periods">
      <td *ngFor="let item of myFormGroup.get('periods').controls, let periodIndex=index"
          style="padding:7px;"
          [formGroupName]="periodIndex">
        <input type="text"
               formControlName="value1"
               style="width:35px;" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: About brackets or not, think that if you use brakets, Angular think that the other side is an "expresion" and try to evaluate, e.g. `[formArrayName]="periods"`, Angular look for a variable "periods" in your component. About formGroupName, you has an array of formGroup, you need indicate the formGroup, you can indicate using the "index" `[formGroupName]="periodIndex"` or even using the variable of for and formGroup `[formGroup]="item"`. About patchValue, pathValue not add (or remove) elements to your formArray, simply fill with values